# Stored Procedure taking too much time

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

i'm facing a problem. i'm using a stored procedure to retrieve some set of data. this procedure is optimized by all DB expect and retrieving result in 0 sec. but after some days it takes too much time and i have to re-compile it after 3,4 days by using autojob. after re-compiling it again retrieving result in 0 sec. 
can any one help me out is there any permanent solution for this issue.?

**code:**

```
DECLARE @account BIGINT = 2210124537100405 
        WITH RECOMPILE

BEGIN
    -- declare @account bigint =101125953510789

    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, table2.number) AS Claim_No,
           Table2.account,
           CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), B_DATE, 101) AS BILLDATE,
           table2.Location_Code,
           DOS,
           CONVERT(VARCHAR, DOS, 101)     AS DOS_SERVICE,
           (
               SELECT ISNULL(p_name, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(p_2name, '') + '. ' + 
                      ISNULL(p_3name, '')
               FROM   table3 p
               WHERE  p.p_code = a_p
           )                              AS A_Pn,
           B_Phn,
           S_Phn,
           ISNULL(C_Total, 0.00)             C_Total,
           ISNULL(Amt_P, 0.00)               Amt_P,
           PA_NUMBER,
           Re_Number,
           Facility_Code,
           ho_to = CASE ISNULL(Ho_To, '')
                        WHEN '' THEN dot
                        ELSE Hos_To
                   END,
           Hos_Fr = CASE ISNULL(Hos_From, '')
                         WHEN '' THEN dost
                         ELSE Hos_From
                    END,
           PRI_STATUS,
           SEC_STATUS,
           OTH_STATUS,
           PAT_STATUS,
           Employment,
           Claim_Status,
           Claim_Status_Date,
           Accident_State,
           Phy_Exam_Code,
           Phy_Exam_Desc,
           Ordering_Physician,
           ICN_Number,
           Block1213,
           ISNULL(Pri_Ins_Payment, 0.00)  AS Pri_Ins_Payment,
           ISNULL(Sec_Ins_Payment, 0.00)  AS Sec_Ins_Payment,
           ISNULL(Oth_Ins_Payment, 0.00)  AS Oth_Ins_Payment,
           ISNULL(Patient_Payment, 0.00)  AS Patient_Payment,
           ISNULL(Adjustment, 0.00)       AS Adjustment,
           ISNULL(Amt_Due, 0.00)          AS Amt_Due,
           DX_Code1,
           DX_Code2,
           DX_Code3,
           DX_Code4,
           DX_Code5,
           DX_Code6,
           DX_Code7,
           DX_Code8,
           POS,
           table2.PTL_Status,
           ISNULL(table2.resolve, 0)         resolve,
           table2.Patient_Payment_Plan,
           Is_Self_Pay,
           table2.Deleted,
           UPPER(table2.Created_By)       AS Created_By,
           CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR, table2.Created_Date, 101)) AS 
           Created_Date,
           table2.Modified_By,
           table2.Modified_Date,
           IS_DRAFT                       AS Is_draft,
           ISNULL(ClaimTemp_Category.Temp_Name, '') AS Temp_Name,
           (
               SELECT COUNT(claim_no) AS table2_Submitted
               FROM   table2_Submitted
               WHERE  Claim_No        = table2.Claim_No
                      AND DELETED     = 0
           )                              AS table2_Submitted,
           (
               SELECT COUNT(claim_payments_id) AS CLAIMS_PAYMENT FROMtable4
               WHERE  Claim_No        = table2.Claim_No
                      AND DELETED     = 0
           )                              AS CLAIMS_PAYMENT
    FROM   table2
           JOIN table3
                ON  table2.attending_physician = table3.provider_code
           LEFT OUTER JOIN ClaimTemp_Category
                ON  table2.no = ClaimTemp_Category.Claim_No
    WHERE  (
               table2.account = @account
               OR table2.DRAFT_account = @account
           )
           AND ISNULL(table2.DELETED, 0) = 0
    ORDER BY
           DOS DESC
END
```

Comment: Can you share the procedure code? Asking for help optimizing with no code is kind of silly.

Comment: Search for parameter sniffing

Comment: As a guess I would say you have parameter sniffing going on. Or perhaps an execution plan generated with one set of parameters that is less than optimal for another run. There are many reasons for this sort of thing.

Comment: if it always runs that fast, even on first execution, check into option recompile

Comment: you need to compare the plans when it's running well, when it's not, etc.